# Sum of following digits

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

```
number = 96154# Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sequence_len = 3 # Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sum=0
numbstr=str(number)
digitlist=[]

for digit in numbstr:
 digitlist.append(int(digit))

while sum!=10 or len(digitlis)<sequence_len:
sum=0
if len(digitlist)>=3:
    for i in range(0,3):
        sum=sum+digitlist[i]
    del digitlist [i]

print sum
```

The code needs to check whether there is a sum of a sequence of following digits (for example 3 ) which its sum is 10 and print an information about it

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, can you correct it?

Comment: What error do you see? A `NameError` for `digitlis` perhaps?

Comment: Won't fix the problem, but your `for` loop to sum your digits can just be `sum = sum(digitlist[:3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. `...len(digitlis)<sequence_len...`, your variable is missing a `t`.
2. Secondly, I have no clue as to what your code does, the logic is not *very* intuitive.

However, here is a simple program, that does what you want it to do, and I kept it as simple as possible:

```
number = 343703  # Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sequence_len = 3  # Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
numbstr = str(number)
digitlist = []

# Appending all the numbers to a list
for digit in numbstr:
    digitlist.append(int(digit))

# Looping over all the variables in digitlist, i is the index
for i, _ in enumerate(digitlist):
    # If the index, i is 2 less than the length of the list
    if i < len(digitlist) - 2:
        # Adding the term and the next two terms after that
        if digitlist[i] + digitlist[i+1] + digitlist[i+2] == 10:
            # Printing the list
            print digitlist[i:i+3]
```

[Working example.](http://ideone.com/nE4JCd)

Answer (score 0):

After the for loop, `i` will be 3. So `del digitlist [i]` will delete the 3rd element instead of the 1st element. Replace that with `del digitlist [0]`. Also, `len(digitlis)<sequence_len` in your while statement condition should be `len(digitlis)>=sequence_len`. Finally, there is a spelling mistake; `len(digitlis)` should be `len(digitlist)`.

Corrected code:

```
number = 96154# Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sequence_len = 3 # Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sum=0
numbstr=str(number)
digitlist=[]

for digit in numbstr:
 digitlist.append(int(digit))
# len(digitlis)<sequence_len → len(digitlist)>sequence_list
while sum!=10 or len(digitlist)>sequence_len: # 
    sum=0
    if len(digitlist)>=3:
        for i in range(0,3):
            sum=sum+digitlist[i]
        del digitlist [0] # del digitlist [i] → del digitlist [0]

print sum
```

A more compact version utilizing Python's features:

```
DESIRED_SUM=10
number = 96154# Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
sequence_len = 3 # Replace ??? with a value of your choice.
digit_list = list(map(int,str(number)))
# Note that if len(digit_list)-sequence_len+1 is negative, the range function will return an empty list, making the generator comprehension empty. any() returns False on an empty iterator (a generator is an iterator).
indexes = [i for i in range(len(digit_list)-sequence_len+1) if sum(digit_list[i:i+sequence_len])==DESIRED_SUM]
if len(indexes) > 0:
    print "{sequence_len} consecutive digits in {number} have a sum of {DESIRED_SUM}.".format(**vars())
else:
    print "No {sequence_len} consecutive digits have a sum of {DESIRED_SUM}.".format(**vars())
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete code -how do I create a list (inside this code of the following digits that there sum is 10)?

Comment: Thank you very much sir , I've found the solution for creating the list of the following digits that there sum is 10 ) thanks again!

Comment: @user2928714 `digit_list[i:i+DESIRED_SUM]` Please upvote my answer if it is helpful. If you think my answer is the best, accept my answer by ticking the green tick mark next to my answer.

Comment: Thanks ,found a solution by myself by emptying a list after entenring the while loop ,and inserting diigits into the list in the for loop ,still thanks!

Comment: I would like to vote up but my reputation is still lower than 15 :-(

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
digitlist=[]

for digit in numbstr:
 digitlist.append(int(digit))
```

can be simply replaced by:

```
digitlist = [int(i) for i in str(number)]
```

To calculate the sum, just call the sum function on the list:

```
sum(digitlist)
```